# Syntax highlighting inside HTML5 <script> tags

Tags: syntax-highlighting, minor-mode, html, javascript, multiple-modes

I was curious if there was a way to get highlighting/indentation for any JavaScript that's inside of HTML5  tags? I don't frequently use JavaScript but for a class I'm in we're working with it. I assume it would be a matter of creating a JavaScript minor-mode and then hooking that into the HTML5 mode?

Answer (score 2):

There's a major mode that can highlight nested languages for web along with server-side scripting languages like PHP and template languages. It's better than `html-mode` for HTML editing as well, since it understands indentation better and avoids doing silly things like indenting contents of `<pre>` tags.

It's called `web-mode`.

Here's a [link to it's page](http://web-mode.org/), and here's the [repo](https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/) with it.